# Uniqueness of solutions of quasilinear equation $(y+u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = x-y$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Uniqueness of quasilinear equation $(y+u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = x-y$ with initial condition $u(x,1)=1+x$. Prove that the solution is unique in $C^1 (\Omega)$, where $\Omega = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2, y>0 \}$. I tried method of characteristics to solve it explicitly but failed since it seems quite tricky. Instead, I found the link(http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111103021/7.pdf), where Theorem 6 gives the uniqueness condition and I checked and it works here, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

Solving the PDE in order to only prove the uniqueness of solution isn't a smart method. But it works anyway.

The method of characteristics is not tricky at all (see below). It leads to a unique solution :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{2}{y}+x-y$$

[image]

Comment: How does the the first equality in line 2

$$\frac{dx}{y+u} = \frac{du}{x-y}$$

produce

$$\frac{dx + du}{(y+u)+(x-y)}$$

? Also, you have three equalities in a row there, which I assume is a typo, though I'm not sure. I assume the last one should be an implication of sorts?

Comment: This is a general property of the fractions : If $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}$ then $$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{k_1 A+k_2C}{k_1B+k_2D}$$

Comment: @JJacquelin How did you know such $F$ exists? (after "General solution:"). More precisely, how do you go from $c_2$ to $F$?

Comment: This is a key point of the method of characteristics. If one didn't study the theory he cannot understand. It is not possible to put in a few words what requires pages of textbook. The general solution is expressed on the form of implicit equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$ where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables. Alternatively the general solution can be expressed on the form $c_2=F(c_1)$ or $c_1=G(c_2)$ which are any different functions of one variable. You  cannot say if such a function or an infinity of such functions exist or not, until the boundary conditions be specified.

Comment: The question "How did you know such $F$  exists" is ambiguous. Are you talking of $F$ in the equation of the general solution (without boundary conditions) or of $F$ in the equation of particular solution(s) according to given boundary conditions ?